# Exchange 2010 Export Mailbox

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010, export

I'm trying to export a mailbox to PST, and I'm getting the following output:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Export-Mailbox -Identity dsprague -PSTFolderPath F:\Export -verbose
VERBOSE: [17:07:37.950 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Active Directory session settings for 'Export-Mailbox' are:  View Entire
Forest: 'False', Default Scope: 'HEADQUARTERS.LOCAL', Configuration Domain Controller:
'IGIVANNSP02.HEADQUARTERS.LOCAL', Preferred Global Catalog: 'IGIVANNSP02.HEADQUARTERS.LOCAL', Preferred Domain
Controllers: '{ IGIVANNSP02.HEADQUARTERS.LOCAL }'
VERBOSE: [17:07:37.952 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Runspace context: Executing user: HEADQUARTERS.LOCAL/Users/Administrator,
Executing user organization: , Current organization: , RBAC-enabled: Enabled.
VERBOSE: [17:07:37.954 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Beginning processing.
VERBOSE: [17:07:37.955 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Instantiating handler with index 0 for cmdlet extension agent "Admin Audit
 Log Agent".
VERBOSE: [17:07:37.979 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Trying to open registry key
'Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\OUTLOOK.EXE'.
VERBOSE: [17:07:37.980 GMT] Export-Mailbox : The default value of the registry key is 'C:\PROGRA~2\Microsoft
Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE'.
VERBOSE: [17:07:37.983 GMT] Export-Mailbox : The version of Outlook.exe is '14.0.4760.1000'.
VERBOSE: [17:07:37.985 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Current ScopeSet is: {Domain Read Scope: {, }, Domain Write Scope(s): {,
}, Configuration Scope: {, }, Server Configuration Scope(s): {, }, , Exclusive Scope: {, }}
VERBOSE: [17:07:37.988 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Searching objects "dsprague" of type "ADUser" under the root "$null".
VERBOSE: [17:07:37.995 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Previous operation run on global catalog server
'IGIVANNSP01.HEADQUARTERS.LOCAL'.
VERBOSE: [17:07:37.996 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Processing object "HEADQUARTERS.LOCAL/Users/Dan Sprague".
VERBOSE: [17:07:38.020 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Searching objects "Mailbox Database 2117198641" of type "MailboxDatabase"
under the root "$null".
VERBOSE: [17:07:38.025 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Previous operation run on domain controller 'IGIVANNSP01'.
VERBOSE: [17:07:38.035 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Exporting mailbox 'HEADQUARTERS.LOCAL/Users/Dan Sprague' from server
'IGIVANMXP01.HEADQUARTERS.LOCAL' to F:\Export\dsprague.pst.
VERBOSE: [17:07:38.040 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Searching objects "Mailbox Database 2117198641" of type "MailboxDatabase"
under the root "$null".
VERBOSE: [17:07:38.043 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Previous operation run on domain controller 'IGIVANNSP01'.
VERBOSE: Exporting mailbox content from the mailbox 'Dan Sprague' into PST file 'F:\Export\dsprague.pst'. This
operation may take a long time to complete.
VERBOSE: [17:07:38.056 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Resolved current organization: .
VERBOSE: [17:07:38.058 GMT] Export-Mailbox : Ending processing.
VERBOSE: [17:07:38.059 GMT] Export-Mailbox : [dsprague] The operation has started.
VERBOSE: [17:07:38.060 GMT] Export-Mailbox : [dsprague] Initializing MAPI; loading library.
Error was found for Dan Sprague (dsprague@igi-hq.com) because: The operation failed., error code: -2147467259
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [Export-Mailbox], RecipientTaskException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 6B6095DF,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.ExportMailbox
```

Does anyone have any ideas what's going wrong here? I've installed Outlook 2010 x64 on a mailbox server, and I'm running this command from the exchange management console.

Comment: Can you look in your application logs and see if anything is showing up there?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found this. It may be an option. Try running the powershell as administrator then running the command. This is apparently a known issue

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchange2010/thread/886a6c39-b975-408a-827c-fb3c07ea579b

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Grant Full Access Rights**

```
New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Role "Mailbox Import Export" –User Administrator
```

**Step 2: Create a Network Share to save Exported PST files.**

Grant Exchange Trusted Subsystem group read/write permission
[image]

**Step 3: Run New-MailboxExportReuqest**

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox EricSimson -FilePath "\\SERVER01\PSTFileShare\EricSimson_Recovered.pst"
```

You can check the status of active export jobs with [Get-MailboxExportRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailboxexportrequest?view=exchange-ps) command.

More detailed steps are [available here](https://www.msb365.blog/?p=3899).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Exchange 2010 then you can follow this method to export exchange data to PST file format:

**Step 1:** Create a Shared Folder for PST File Access

**Step 2:** Grant Appropriate Rights to User First, go to Exchange Admin Centre

**Step 3:** Save Data into PST format

Visit **helpful [link](https://exchange-server-guide.blogspot.com/2018/03/export-exchange-2010-mailbox-to-pst.html)** to understand the complete process with screenshots of the Export process.